# Stopping and cleaning up in Play Framework 2.3.x

Tags: playframework, akka, entitymanager

I know that there is an onStop() in the GlobalSettings where it is possible to close threads/connection pools but if you have scheduled jobs in the Akka scheduler that uses those pools, the pools are stopped first before the akka system shuts down.

Any way of working around this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? This is kind of vague.

Comment: Sorry about that. I want to be able to stop the akka system first before closing the pools so that all the scheduled jobs are properly ended. If I close the pools on the onStop, the pools are closed first before the akka system finishes to run the jobs